# Why changing one item in a linq group affects other items in the same group?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm working on some C# code similar like this:

```
public class Item
{
   public bool flag { get; set; }
   public string itemName { get; private set;};

   Item(string _name)
   {
       this.itemName = _name;
       this.flag     = false;
   }
}

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main() 
    {
        List itemList = new List<Item>();
        itemList.Add(new Item("ProductA");
        itemList.Add(new Item("ProductA");
        itemList.Add(new Item("ProductB");

        var itemGroups = from item in itemList group item by item.itemName;
        foreach (var itemGroup in itemGroups)
        {
            foreach (Item i in itemGroup)
            {
                i.flag = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

What I want to achieve here is to change only one item in a group without touching other items in the same group. From above code, I'm expecting that only the 1st item with itemName "ProductA" has its flag set to true. But the result is that Both the items (with itemName "ProductA") have its flag being set to true.

I'm new to linq. Is something I'm doing wrong? Or how can I achieve the goal here?

Many thanks!!!

Doug

Comment: you have 2 items with the same name. `ProductA`

Comment: `But the result is that Both the items (with itemName "ProductA") have its flag being set to true` Debug your code again. It works as you expect.

Comment: Are you *sure* this is your actual code? Are you *sure* you haven't added the same item reference twice, so that in fact you only have 1 product A, but the same one is listed twice? Meaning, can you reproduce the problem in the above code or is that code dumbed down for the question?

Answer (score 1):

I am not able to reproduce your scenario as it has each item to be unique of type `Item`. May be in your code, you could have accidentally added an item twice to your list like

```
Item item1 = new Item("ProductA");
listItem.Add(item1);
....
listItem.Add(item1);
```

In this case at any later point of time, if you updated the item with itemname as "ProductA", then that change will be reflected in two elements of the list. Please check this case.

Comment: Thanks guys! It's my Bad. I did add the same instance twice. The sample should work as expected.

Comment: Then I suggest you accept this answer to your question, glad you worked it out :) Also, consider downloading [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) and try your code in there before posting, it will make it easier for both you and others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

> What I want to achieve here is to change only one item in a group
>   without touching other items in the same group. From above code, I'm
>   expecting that only the 1st item with itemName "ProductA" has its flag
>   set to true.

Your code is fine, check in the debugger:

```
//ProductA
itemGroups.ToList()[0].ToList()[0].flag //true
itemGroups.ToList()[0].ToList()[1].flag //false

//ProductB
itemGroups.ToList()[1].ToList()[0].flag //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code enumerates all item in a group.

```
        foreach (Item i in itemGroup)
        {
            i.flag = true;
            break;
        }
```

You need get First one. Use First or FirstOrDefault methods